# Topological rigidity of compact manifolds in dimension three 

Tags: 3-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology

The Borel Conjecture asserts that homotopy equivalent aspherical closed manifolds are homeomorphic, which is still open in general.
But, for three-dimensional manifolds, this conjecture holds   (I read this in [Bessieres-Besson-Boileau](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~lbessier/english_principal.pdf)), whose proof depends on the geometrization theorem (Perelman).

Question:
Does the relative version of the Borel conjecture also hold for compact 3-manifolds with boundary (by the geometrization)?
The relative version: If there is a homotopy equivalence between two compact aspherical manifolds that is a homeomorphism between their boundaries,  are those manifolds homeomorphic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

When the manifolds are Haken this is a theorem of Waldhausen. See Ian Agol's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35680/complete-knot-invariant/35687#35687).

Since your manifolds are aspherical, they are irreducible by the Poincaré conjecture.  Since they have boundary and are irreducible, they are Haken.

Comment: Could you please give a brife proof that geometrization conjecture implies Borel conjecutre in dimension 3? I read [BBB], it seems they didn't explictely proved Borel Conjecture, just said it's a corollary of GC, which I don't know why.

Comment: @unknown: The Poincar&eacute; Conjecture implies that a $3$--manifold is irreducibile if it is aspherical. Say your manifolds are $M$ and $N$.  If they are homotopy equivalent, they have isomorphic fundamental groups.  If this group does not contain a $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ subgroup, then $M$ and $N$ are hyperbolic, by Geometrization, and so, by Mostow Rigidity, they are homeomorphic. 

Comment: @unkown: Continued: If this group contains a $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ subgroup, then, by the (strong) Torus Theorem, $M$ and $N$ are either Haken or small Seifert fibered spaces.  If both are Haken, then Waldhausen's theorem comes to the rescue.  I think you do something like show that $\pi_1$ of a small SFS isn't an amalgamated product to rule out $M$ Haken and $N$ a small SFS.  If both are small SFSs, then the euler class tells you they're homeomorphic.

Comment: @unkown: Actually, to rule out $M$ Haken and $N$ small SFS, argue like this:  $\pi_1$ has infinite cyclic center, and so $M$ is a SFS too (this is part of the proof of the Strong Torus Theorem).  The center is a completely algebraic thing, and so the quotient of $\pi_1(M)$ by the center is the orbifold fundamental group of the underlying orbifold of the Seifert fibered structure on $M$.  This must be isomorphic to the orbifold group for the underlying orbifold for $N$, and so $M$ is a small SFS.  Euler class to the rescue.