# Theory of Irrational Tangles?

Tags: knot-theory, continued-fractions

According to one possible definition, an $n$-tangle $T$ is a subset $T \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2\times [0,1] =: X$ that is homeomorphic to a disjoint union $[0,1] \times n := [0,1] \amalg \ldots \amalg [0,1]$ of $n$ copies of the unit interval via an embedding $\iota: [0,1]\times n \hookrightarrow X$ mapping the $2n$ endpoints $\{0,1\}\times n$ onto the $2n$ marked points $\{0,\ldots{},n-1\}\times\{0\}\times \{0,1\}$.

Two tangles $T, T'$ are said to be equivalent, if there is an isotopy $\phi: [0,1] \rightarrow \text{Homeo}(X)$, $\phi(0) = \text{id}$ fixing the boundaries, i.e. such that $\phi(t)(x) = x$ for all $t \in [0,1], x \in \Bbb{R}^2\times \{0,1\}$, such that $\phi(1)(T) = T'$.

There is a remarkable class of $2$-tangles discovered by Conway, the *rational tangles* which up to equivalence can all be obtained from the trivial $2$-tangle $T = \{0,1\} \times [0,1]$ by an action of $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$ on tangle diagrams, described in terms of (redundant) generators as follows:
[image: action on tangles]

The theory shows that there is a bijection

$$ \frac{\{\text{rational tangles }T\}}{\text{equivalence}} \simeq \Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{Q}) $$

that's equivariant for the natural actions of $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$. In essence, the proof relies on the theory of continued fractions. In particular, to any *finite* continued fraction expression
$$[a_0; a_1,\ldots,a_n](X)$$
defined recursively by
$$[](X) := X,\ [a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}](X) := [a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_n](a_{n+1} + X^{-1})$$
 one can associate a corresponding rational tangle by formally substituting the trivial tangle for $X$ and expanding this formal fraction using the description of the actions of the generators of $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$.

Now, once you accept that rational tangles are basically the same thing as finite continued fractions the obvious questions becomes:

**What about infinite continued fractions? Is there a theory of "irrational" tangles?**

The irrational tangle corresponding to an infinite continued fraction
$$[a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots]$$
should of course be the limit (in an appropriate sense) of the sequence of rational tangles corresponding to the sequence $x_k$ of *convergents*
$$ x_k = [a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_k](\infty) \in \Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{Q})$$
of the real number $x = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k$ defined by that continued fraction, so that in the end you get something that looks like a *wild knot* (see the picture [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300961/how-to-add-essentially-new-knots-to-the-universe)). In particular, one might hope that there is a $\text{PGL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$-equivariant map
$$ \Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{R}) \longrightarrow \frac{\text{$2$-tangles}}{\text{equivalence}} $$

**Has such a theory ever been worked out?**

Comment: There is a sketch of such a theory in Kauffman and Lambropoulou's "On the classification of rational tangles" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311499.pdf): see pp.23-26 (in particular Figures 15 & 16!)